# Use Letsencrypt for multiple domains in Lighttpd

Tags: lets-encrypt, lighttpd

For me it seems that a lot of guides / info about Lighttpd and Letsencrypt is outdated (5+ years).
I have a newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 server with Lighttpd and 20+ virtual domains on 1 ip.
How do I install LetsEncrypt certificates in this setup in an easy way and keep them updated?

I was using Hiawatha webserver before, where it was very easy since the creator included a script that parsed out all domains from the config file and requested new cert's for them.

I have found guides for single domains where you need to merge files etc (to create .pem files) but how is this done for multiple domains in a good way?

I'm also pointing some domains to the same file : example1.com and example2.com shows the same file (/var/www/example.com/public/index.html).

I find it confusing that I can't seem to find this information easily. Most info about Lighttpd seem to be old.

Answer (score 1):

> I find it confusing that I can't seem to find this information easily. Most info about Lighttpd seem to be old.

If you focused on primary sources of information, you would have easily found the official lighttpd documentation https://wiki.lighttpd.net/

[lighttpd TLS documentation](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL)

[lighttpd TLS Let's Encrypt](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/HowToSimpleSSL)

> I have found guides for single domains where you need to merge files etc (to create .pem files) but how is this done for multiple domains in a good way?

This is no longer needed (though still supported) since lighttpd 1.4.53, which introduced `ssl.privkey` alongside `ssl.pemfile`

Comment: That helped. Strange that I didn't see it while Googling.

I still do not see how to setup this with multiple domains. All examples include one domain like:  `ssl.privkey= "/etc/lighttpd/certs/www.example.com/privkey.pem"`

Also unclear about how to handle all the PEM-files, but this might be more clear when understanding hot to handle multiple domains.

Comment: I found it should be something like this:
    $SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/default.pem"
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "example1.com" {
            ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/example1.com.pem"
        }
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "example2.com" {
            ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/example2.com.pem"
        }
    }